# Images not aligning below text

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, diagrams

I have some text and I want the images I have inserted to show up below it. However when I try to insert the image it appears to move to the next column, How do I have the image to be position immediately below the last line of text?

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\caption{Original Image}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure/orig.png} 
\end{center}



\begin{center}
\caption{Image Watermarked on the $4^{th}$ plane}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure/plane_4.png} 
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. It might for example be that your images are too big to be left in the column and `float` to the next one.

Comment: Please refer to this link for a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 1):

From data, which you provide, I only can suggest to add option `h` to `figure` environment. If after line, to which follows figure is enough place, figure will stay there, otherwise it will move on top to next column/page.

```
\begin{figure}[h]% <--- h as here, sometime help !h
    \centering
\caption{Original Image}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure/orig.png}

\caption{Image Watermarked on the $4^{th}$ plane}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure/plane_4.png}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this, I know super late but instead of just [h] use [!h]

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[scale=.75]{q16}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this package
`\usepackage{float}`

then in the figure, put the [H] instead of [!h] or [h]
it works for me

```
\begin{figure}[H]
         \centering              
         \includegraphics[width=34cm,height=7cm,keepaspectratio]{image screenshots/connect wallet/3 sign msg.png}
         \caption{Required signing message}
     \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What happens, if on the page4 is not sufficient space for image?